# NVelocity - Only show row if not null

Tags: c#, nvelocity

I have the following in my NVelocity template:

```
#if($PO.GiftMessage != '')
<tr>
    <td align="left">
      <font face="arial" size="2" color="#000000">
        <b>Gift Message</b>
        <br />
        $PO.GiftMessage
      </font>
    </td>
</tr>
#end
```

Basically if my object (PO) has the property GiftMessage, and it is not null, i want to display that tr....
It's not currently working -
Have i got my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using this...

```
#if($PO.GiftMessage) 
    #if($PO.GiftMessage !="")
         ...whatever....
    #end
#end
```

Basically this line:

```
if($PO.GiftMessage)
```

returns "true" if $PO.GiftMessage is not null (this could still be a string.empty value, hence my nested if statement below it)

Answer (score 0):

it would be cleaner to put it in a single IF statement

```
#if($PO.GiftMessage && $PO.GiftMessage !="")
      ...whatever....
#end
```